Let $a, b, c > 0$ and $a+b+c=1$, then prove that, ${1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c} \leq 3+{{2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}\over{abc}}$
Let $a, b, c > 0$ and $a+b+c=1$, then prove that, ${1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c} \leq 3 + {{2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}\over{abc}}$
If I rewrite this question like
$${{bc+ac+ab}\over abc} \leq {3abc + {2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}\over{abc}}$$
So, then I need compare only
$${bc+ac+ab} \leq 3abc + {2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}\tag{1}$$
Overall I understand equation holds, when $a=b=c={1\over3}$
But, how I can prove (1)?

Try multiplying the left-hand side by $a+b+c$.

It's a common approach to make the degree of each side equal when a given condition lets us ascend/descend the degree.

Observe that for $x,y>0,$ in view of $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy,$ we have $$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)\ge (x+y)xy=x^2y+xy^2$$ Thus
$$2(a^3+b^3+c^3)=(a^3+b^3)+(b^3+c^3)+(a^3+c^3)\\ \ge a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+bc^2+a^2c+ac^2$$ Hence
$$ 2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+3abc\\
\ge (a^2b+ab^2+abc)+(b^2c+bc^2+abc)+(a^2c+ac^2+abc)\\
=ab(a+b+c)+bc(a+b+c)+ac(a+b+c)
\\ =ab+bc+ac$$ This gives $(1).$

Alternatively, you can write :
$$ab+bc+ca \le 3abc+2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\\\iff\\ (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\le 3abc+2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\iff
2(a^3+b^3+c^3) \ge \sum_{\text{cyc}} ab(a+b)$$
And yes, this inequality is also , a direct application of AM-GM inequality.

I would take a different approach, as I mentioned in the comment.
(I commented on this to suggest a various direction, but I found it a bit interesting so I'm posting it here.)
(This is not the answer of your last inequality: $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} ab \leq 3abc+2\sum_{cyc}a^3$, but the answer to the original inequality below.)

$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac 1 a \leq 3 + 2\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{a^2}{bc}, a, b, c > 0, a+b+c=1.$

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\cycsum}{\sum_{\text{cyc}}}
\newcommand{\symsum}{\sum_{\text{sym}}}
& \text{Enough to show that: } \cycsum \dfrac{a+b+c}{a} \leq 3+2\cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc}. \\
\Leftrightarrow \; & \cycsum\dfrac{b+c}{a} \leq 2\cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc}. \\
\Leftrightarrow \; & \symsum \dfrac{a}{b} \leq 2\cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc}. \\
\ \\
&\text{Let } \cycsum \dfrac b a = S_1, \cycsum \dfrac a b = S_2. \\
& \left(\cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc}\right) \left( \cycsum \dfrac b c \right) \ge \left( \cycsum \dfrac a c \right)^2, \cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc} \geq \dfrac{S_1^2}{S_2}. \\
&\text{ISW, } \cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc} \geq \dfrac{S_2^2}{S_1}. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & 2\cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc} \geq \dfrac{S_1^3+S_2^3}{S_1S_2}. \\
& \dfrac{S_1^2-S_1S_2+S_2^2}{S_1S_2} = \dfrac{S_1}{S_2}-1+\dfrac{S_2}{S_1} \geq 2\sqrt{\dfrac{S_1}{S_2} \cdot \dfrac{S_2}{S_1}} - 1 = 1.\\
\ \\
\Rightarrow \; & \dfrac{S_1^3+S_2^3}{S_1S_2} = (S_1+S_2) \dfrac{S_1^2-S_1S_2+S_2^2}{S_1S_2} \geq S_1+S_2 = \cycsum \dfrac{b}{a} + \cycsum \dfrac{a}{b} = \symsum \dfrac{a}{b}. \\
\therefore \; & \symsum \dfrac{a}{b} \leq 2\cycsum \dfrac{a^2}{bc}. \blacksquare
\end{align}
